# iOS universal links not working from gmail app

Tags: ios, gmail, ios-universal-links

I have implemented iOS universal links to my app and everything is working fine when link is send to email and triggered from mail app, but not works when triggered from gmail app (opens link in embedded browser). I find out that some other app links such as Youtube or TestFlight is working from gmail app. Please help me to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can u post your code of gmail and mail

Comment: This is not about the code it's about the universal links or some setup to make gmail app open universal links in my app instead of embedded browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Universal Links only work in Gmail under very specific circumstances: the embedded webview needs to be already open, so clicking a Universal Link directly from the text of an email doesn't work. You can find a list with more information [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links).

It's possible YouTube and TestFlight actually aren't using Universal Links to trigger those apps. I haven't looked at them recently.

Comment: I have a problem with universal links for Gmail as well. You said that Gmail works under very specific circumstances. Can you please say that circumstances?

Comment: @david in the past, links didn't work directly from the email content. You had to click through to a page in the embedded webview, and then click a valid universal link. Seems this is now fixed though.

Comment: For me universal link worked only when I was logged with Safari. With gmaill app it was not working at all

Comment: A workaround for it https://stephenradford.me/link-to-url-scheme-or-not-and-force-out-of-the-app-youre-in/

Comment: @Rubycon the workaround solution you mentioned in your comment does not work.