# How iOS URL Scheme work with a https website

Tags: ios, url, swift5, url-scheme

I was developing an iOS application which need to work with a website. I'm not the owner of website so I cant use the universal link. I tried to open the website url `https://example.com/xxx/xxx` directly when I set the `https://example.com/xxx/xxx` as URL Scheme , however it will only display the website but won't asked for open the apps. What is the problem and can I do to achieve the expectation below?

Expectation:
When the user open the website

- Phone w/ app - open the website and ask for open the app
- Phone w/o app - open the website

I have similar problem with this question.
[iOS URL scheme or not existing Universal Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557377/ios-url-scheme-or-not-existing-universal-link#)

Comment: Have you verified that app & website aren't registered to support universal deep linking? You can look for the `apple-app-site-association` file at the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't own the website you want to deep link to, you can't dictate the behavior once the user lands on that destination in their browser – that would need to be handled by that website.

Comment: so means to hit the expectation, I need the AASA file in the website and apply the universal link right?